# $5x\big(1+\frac{1}{x^2 +y^2}\big)=12$ ; $5y\big(1-\frac{1}{x^2 +y^2}\big)=4$ find $x$ and $y$

Tags: polynomials

I already tried to solve using substitution and cross multiplication method .
I got the first simplified

(1)$$\frac{12}{5x}=1+ \frac{1}{x^2} +y^2$$
(2)
$$\frac{4}{5y}=1- \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$

Adding (1) and (2)

$$12y +4x= 50xy$$
I am pretty sure that it is irrelevant as there has to be at be $2$ solutions for $x$ and $y$. Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Working on solution...

Comment: "be at be" is a typo for what?

Comment: When you add (1) and (2), you should get $12y+4x=10xy$. Then you can use the method provided by @FundThmCalculus.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is a good start, now take that expression you got and plug it back into one of your other expressions:
$$12y+4x=50xy \rightarrow (4-50y)x=-12y \rightarrow x=\frac{-12y}{4-50y}$$
$$\frac{12}{5x}=1+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \rightarrow \frac{12(4-50y)}{5*-12y}=\frac{4-50y}{-5y}=1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{-12y}{4-50y} \right)^2+y^2}$$
Factor out the right hand side:
$$\frac{50y-4}{5y}-1=\frac{50y-4-5y}{5y}=\frac{(4-50y)^2}{144y^2+y^2(4-50y)^2}$$
Clear out denominator:
$$(45y-4)(144y^2+y^2(4-50y)^2)=5y(4-50y)^2$$
This will expand to be a quartic polynomial (Wolfram Alpha used):
$$112500 y^5-28000 y^4-3700 y^3+1360 y^2-80 y = 0$$
The solutions are:
$$y=0$$
$$y=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$y = \frac{11}{675}-\frac{6601 (1+i \sqrt{3}}{1350 (-438499+540 i \sqrt{326973})^{1/3}}-((1-i \sqrt{3}) (-438499+540 i sqrt(326973))^{1/3})/1350$$
$$y = \frac{11}{675}-(6601 (1-i \sqrt{3}))/(1350 (-438499+540 i \sqrt{326973})^(1/3))-((1+i \sqrt{3}) (-438499+540 i \sqrt{326973})^(1/3))/1350$$
You would then feed these numbers back into your simple expression to obtain the corresponding $x$.

Comment: Will finish formatting later.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=r\cos\varphi,\, y=r\sin\varphi$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{12}{5r\cos\varphi}=\frac{r^2+1}{r^2}\\
\frac{4}{5r\sin\varphi}=\frac{r^2-1}{r^2}
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{5\cos\varphi}{12}=\frac{r}{r^2+1}\\
\frac{5\sin\varphi}{4}=\frac{r}{r^2-1}
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
\cos\varphi=\frac{12}{5}\cdot\frac{r}{r^2+1}\\
\sin\varphi=\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{r}{r^2-1}
\end{cases}$$
$$\left(\frac{12}{5}\cdot\frac{r}{r^2+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{r}{r^2-1}\right)^2=1,$$
which yields $\frac{5 r^4-26 r^2+5}{r^2-1} = 0$
$r^2=5$ or $r^2=\frac{1}{5}$, substituting $r^2$ back, we obtain $x$ and $y$